# What's the origin of "and sh*t"

Tags: etymology, colloquialisms, phrase-origin

I'm referring specifically to phrases like, "kissing and shit" or "baseball and shit".  Sometimes it is contracted: "n'shit".

Comment: It's just a way of saying "and so forth".  Pretty natural formation, for guys talking together.

Comment: Of course, one could claim that it's an idiom developed in reference to the locality of Meinom, Fading, and Shit in Sudan. https://books.google.com/books?id=a3UPAQAAMAAJ&pg=PA140&lpg=PA140&dq=Meinom,+Fading,+and+Shit,&source=bl&ots=pQhB-Z1NjV&sig=nnp-8ZVIUQQ7XMKC1StB2a3-1IQ&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjG8JiH_KrWAhVGllQKHQ-BBl4Q6AEIKDAA#v=onepage&q=Meinom%2C%20Fading%2C%20and%20Shit%2C&f=false

Comment: [and the rest](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Et_cetera)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

"**And stuff**" has been used in this way since the late 17th century, according to [Green's](https://greensdictofslang.com/entry/l3wzcdy) Dictionary of Slang.

The OED has this definition:

> Worthless ideas, discourse, or writing; nonsense, rubbish. Often coupled with nonsense (chiefly stuff and nonsense, †nonsense and stuff)

with attestations from the 16th century, followed by this:

> *phr.* —— *and stuff*, and such-like useless or uninteresting matters. *colloq*

with attestations starting at the end of the 17th century.

For "**and shit**", [Green's](https://greensdictofslang.com/entry/2jwxjqa) has this:

> [1960s+] (*orig. US black*) a general abstract term, usu. thrown into the end of a sentence, similar to *you know* phr.

(Two earlier uses are also relevant here to see the sense development: "any inferior, rubbishy, shoddy or pretentious thing" from the 1920s, and "any thing (material or otherwise), irrespective of its actual quality, ‘stuff’" from the 1930s.)

The OED's definition is:

> *orig. U.S.* **and shit:** and so on; and similar stuff. Also used simply for emphasis

with attestations starting in 1965.

Thus, it seems certain that "and stuff" is the earlier expression, and "and shit" is simply a cruder synonym that has been introduced.  Of course, with the history forgotten, "and stuff" may now be perceived (and used) as a euphemism for "and shit".

Comment: As a southern Brit, I wouldn't actually have known what "and shit" meant in this context! But I would understand "and stuff".  I tend to think of "shit" as rather a derogative term.

Answer (score 0):

We learn  our language from our others close to us which includes parents sibling, friends and associates. Perhaps since the strong survive and the weak go to the wall, it may include the  desire to appear tough. Before universal education it is possible that the expression did not exist. This expression  may also indicate the social milieu to which the user belongs or with which he/she may wish to be associated.

Answer (score -1):

used to be 'and stuff' or 'etc' ,  but in the 'dumbing down of America',  people did not want to sound 'too intelligent',  so they decided that using 'shit' instead of 'stuff' was 'way cooler'. It meant you were a 'cool' 'dude' or 'dudette'.

Comment: Please [explain your answer](//english.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer), preferably with some supporting statements and [references](//english.stackexchange.com/help/referencing). While opinions are valued, they are not of much help as answers.